# Deleting rows dated older than 3 days old

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am very new to this so please help me or give me some hints if you can. Basically I have a column (`N`) which has rows with dates and notes in the cells. For example, `"12/20 Notes:-Left start site", "09/23 Notes:- Needs more information"`....

As you can see all these cells obviously begin with a date but then there are notes included with it which makes it difficult. Basically I am trying to write some VBA code that will allow me to delete the rows that are dated more than 3 days from the current date.

Comment: Can you change your sheet design so the date is in a cell on its own?

Comment: Do you have some code already that you need help with? Right now this seems like a code writing request.

Comment: Per Chris and Matt, this is a straightforward exercise if you can separate the date into its own cell.  Also, you need to give it a try and post your code.

Comment: So, you want to delete all rows for which the cell in the N-column STARTS with a dat IN mm/dd FORMAT referring to a date older than 3 days, right?

Comment: Yes Dirk thats what I want to do basically but the date is in text format which is throwing me off

Comment: I may have left off some important information and that is not every column in N has notes and not every one of them begins with "Note:". But there is a space after the date whenever a note shows up. And yes I actually thought about what Chris said as well. It is possible to separate the date in a cell of its and then delete it but I cant seem to figure out what my for loop would be like. Any hints? THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim rgNote As Range, clNote As Range
Dim noteDate As Variant, splitDate As Variant, splitNote As Variant
Dim expiredData
```

'   Decide till when notes are considered expired

```
expiredData = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) - 3
```

'   Find the cells to inspect

```
Set rgNote = Intersect(Range("N:N"), Range("N:N").Parent.UsedRange)
If Not rgNote Is Nothing Then
    For Each clNote In rgNote.Cells
```

'           Verify this is realy a note. This realy depends on the structure of your spreadsheet

```
        splitNote = Split(clNote.Formula)
        If UBound(splitNote) > LBound(splitNote) Then
            splitDate = Split(splitNote(LBound(splitNote)), "/")
            If UBound(splitDate) = LBound(splitDate) + 1 Then
```

'                   Extract the date, in this case, we expect them in mm/dd format and assume that they are all in the recent past

```
                noteDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), splitDate(LBound(splitDate)), splitDate(LBound(splitDate) + 1))
                If noteDate > Date Then
                    noteDate = DateSerial(Year(noteDate) - 1, Month(noteDate), Day(noteDate))
                End If
```

'                   If expired, then Delete the row

```
                If noteDate <= expiredData Then
                    clNote.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next clNote
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: first of all thanks so much Dirk. But when I try to apply this, it gives me an out of range error and this line is highlighted, "If UCase(splitNote(LBound(splitNote) + 1)) = "NOTE:" Then"

Comment: first of all thanks so much Dirk. But when I try to apply this, it gives me an error that says "subscript out of range" and this line is highlighted, "If UCase(splitNote(LBound(splitNote) + 1)) = "NOTE:" Then"

Comment: Try again, James: added "If UBound(splitNote) > LBound(splitNote) Then"

Comment: Dirk, I forgot to mention before. Not all notes start with "Note:-". Also some dates have notes beside them and some don't. But regardless they are all in text format and there is a space after the date. So in your code, should I just replace "Note:" with a space, "" ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Dirk, Its giving me an error, "Application-defined or object-defined error", Run time error "1004". And this line is highlighted "splitNote = Split(clNote.Formula)"

Comment: James, this is my last update. If there is still a problem, I expect you to start debugging yourself.